# How to send empty message from js to ros

Tags: ros, ardrone, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use roslibjs and I want to try to send std_msgs/Empty for take_off or land, I tried to send like

takeOff.publish('std_msgs/Empty');

but I receive an error about missing the field

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248984/how-to-send-empty-message-from-js-to-ros/) by [Saif Alabachi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28107/saif-alabachi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you, i figure it out, it is only

takeOff.publish();

Because it is empty message!

---

Originally posted by [Saif Alabachi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28107/saif-alabachi/) with karma: 26 on 2016-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-29**:
I would actually recommend to use a Service with the [std_srvs/Trigger](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_srvs/html/srv/Trigger.html) type. That communicates intent in a much more explicit way than `std_msgs/Empty`.